# Is there a way for bypassing the usage of prefix 'sudo'

Tags: rhel, sudo, cifs

I am able to execute all the by using the prefix `sudo`. As of now I was able to remove the password dependency for user `qedbuser`.

I would like to not use the word `sudo`. One my application is trying to save a file in CIFS (SMB) file system. This has been mounted in the local. Every time I run the application. I am getting a error message permission is denied.

1. Is there a way to not use the key word `sudo`?
2. Is there a way to save and create files in the mounted location without using the key word `sudo`?

Note: I have logged in as domain user.

The following are the privileges for the folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Mar 22 16:00 archives
```

This is a mounted folder and this was mounted using command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=qedbuser,password=****,domain=EUR //10.60.33.3/ffff/ProductionEnvironment /home/local/EUR/qedbuser/nb/aa/archives/
```

Comment: `sudo` is a utility, not a keyword in the shell. You can't omit using `sudo` to run things as another user.

Comment: root doesn't mix well with NFS (root can write to NFS of course, but remote NFS server must allow it), have you tried as normal user ? are both local user id and user id on NFS server same ?

Comment: both the local user and user id on NFS is the same.

Comment: I have provide full access priviliges to all the users for the specific file.

Comment: yes but sudo by default will make you root, and root by default is denied from writing to NFS mount point.

Comment: @roaima i not able to understand your statement. please explain

Comment: That's not NFS. It's CIFS. Totally different protocols.

Comment: Does your application run as user `qedbuser`?

Comment: yes it is running as qedbuser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mount` command is missing the `noperm` option. What this does is tell the client to check the username/group against the synthetic ownerships, which in your case are `root` and `root`. By specifying `noperm` the permissions check is deferred to the server.

The man page for `mount.cifs` writes,

> **`perm` Client does permission checks** (vfs_permission check of `uid` and `gid` of the file against the mode and desired operation), Note that this is in addition to the normal ACL check on the target machine done by the server software. Client permission checking is enabled by default.
>
> **`noperm` Client does not do permission checks.** This can expose files on this mount to access by other users on the local client system. It is typically only needed when the server supports the CIFS Unix Extensions but the UIDs/GIDs on the client and server system do not match closely enough to allow access by the user doing the mount. Note that this does not affect the normal ACL check on the target machine done by the server software (of the server ACL against the user name provided at mount time).

This `mount` command should work better for you without the need to use `sudo` for your application:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=qedbuser,password=****,domain=EUR,noperm //10.60.33.3/ffff/ProductionEnvironment /home/local/EUR/qedbuser/nb/aa/archives/
```